# Detect what TreeView node was right-clicked

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I am working on a WPF project and I have added a TreeView to it. I have also created a `ContextMenu` to the TreeView as below:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">

                <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Name="treeViewContextMenu">
                        <MenuItem Header="First option"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Second Option/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TreeView.ContextMenu>

.... </TreeView>
```

Since I add the treeView nodes dinamically, **how can I detect what node was right-clicked in order to open the contextMenu?**

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Does your children have specific own context menu or do they just have the same functionality that you want to do and would just like to know which treeviewitem is selected?

Comment: @LeoLuis they just have the same functionality, ie, there is just on ContextMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I loaded my treeview item's dynamically..

```
  <TreeView Name="treeView" ContextMenuClosing="treeView_ContextMenuClosing">

    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="treeViewContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="First option"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Second Option"/>
            </ContextMenu>
     </TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Hello 1"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Hello 2"/>
     </TreeView>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void treeView_ContextMenuClosing(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
           //Sender should let me determine who sent it from my children/parent

            var parent  = sender as TreeView;
            var children = parent.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
            MessageBox.Show(children.Header.ToString());
        }
```

It's up to you if you want to know the object when the ContextMenu is ***Closed/Open*** or whatever event like when the MenuItem is ***Clicked***.